# what is the alternative for double datatype from spark sql(Databricks) to Sql Server Data warehouse

Tags: sql-server-2016, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I have to load the data from azure datalake to data warehouse.I have created set up for creating external tables.there is one column which is double datatype, i have used decimal type in sql server data warehouse for creating the external table and file format is parquet.But using csv it is working.
i'm getting the following error.

> HdfsBridge::recordReaderFillBuffer - Unexpected error encountered
>   filling record reader buffer: ClassCastException: class
>   java.lang.Double cannot be cast to class parquet.io.api.Binary
>   (java.lang.Double is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap';
>   parquet.io.api.Binary is in unnamed module of loader 'app'.

Can some one help me on this issue?
Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[EXT_TEST1]
( A VARCHAR(10),B decimal(36,19))) 
(DATA_SOURCE = [Azure_Datalake],LOCATION = N'/A/B/PARQUET/*.parquet/',FILE_FORMAT =parquetfileformat,REJECT_TYPE = VALUE,REJECT_VALUE = 1)

Column datatype in databricks:
A string,B double 
Data: A  |  B
      'a'  100.0050
```

Comment: Have you tried float? I think it will be considered a floating point therefore decimal will not work.

Comment: @simon- Thanks for your reply. i have tried float it is working but i want an alternate way for double type in DWH

Answer (score 0):

Use float(53) which is of 53 digits precision and 8 bytes length.